# Where do I define code to release resources allocated in a C Python module init function?

Tags: c++, c, python-2.x, python-c-api

[Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) involves defining a shared library which exposes an [initialization function](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#the-module-s-method-table-and-initialization-function) along the lines of

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC
initspam(void)
{
    (void) Py_InitModule("spam", SpamMethods);
}
```

Assuming I allocate resources here, like allocating a global object via

```
g_bookkeeping = new Bookkeeping;
```

What would be the correct place to write the corresponding `delete` statement? There doesn't seem to be any hook for noticing that a module is unloaded, or is there?

I briefly considered using a global object, like

```
Bookkeeping g_bookkeeping;
```

...but I'd like to have precise control over when that object is constructed or destructed.

The Python documentations [talks about finalization](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html) and mentions a `Py_Finalize()` call which -- at least in Python 2.x -- [internally calls `PyImport_Cleanup`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/pythonrun.c#L457). However, that doesn't seem to do much as far as customizing the module shutdown goes.

Answer (score 1):

[A message to an issue from 2010](https://bugs.python.org/issue9072) states for the version of Python you're using:

> [...]
>
> Please accept that Python indeed does not support unloading modules for severe, fundamental, insurmountable, technical problems, in 2.x.
>
> [...]
>
> Supporting unloading will be (and was) a multi-year project. Don't expect any results in the next five years.

[The documentation for `Py_Finalize()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#c.Py_Finalize) also mentions as **Bugs and caveats:**

> Dynamically loaded extension modules loaded by Python are not unloaded.